# Is upload_url valid for certain time period?

Tags: api, terraform, hashicorp

I was trying to automate the terraform workflow like

1. creation of terraform workspaces/
2. creation of configuration versions/
3. upload configuration files/

In step 2 once the script generates upload_url, then its being called in step 3. When I execute step 3, I can see plan is running in console, but it’s not ended. Then I tried few hours later once again, then I suddenly got Bad Request error.

Could anyone please let me know whether upload_url is calid for certain time period or it’s static once generated.

PFB python code for step 3:

```
import os
import json
import requests

# Fetch the valiables:

WORKSPACE_ID = os.environ['WORKSPACE_ID']
ENV = os.environ["ENV"]
HEADERS = {"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"}
TFC_URL = 'app.terraform.io'
ORGANIZATION = os.environ['ORGANIZATION']
UPLOAD_FILE_NAME = os.environ['UPLOAD_FILE_NAME']
UPLOAD_URL = ""

# Load credentials :
def load_api_credentials():
    path = '/home/gitlab-runner/creds/cred.json'
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        read_data = f.read()
        load_data = json.loads(read_data)
        if ENV == 'prod':
            TFC_API_TOKEN = load_data["TFC_API_TOKEN_PROD"]
        elif ENV == 'test':
            TFC_API_TOKEN = load_data["TFC_API_TOKEN_TEST"]
        else:
            print("Not Found")

        if not TFC_API_TOKEN:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to load credentials at {path}")
        else:
            HEADERS["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {TFC_API_TOKEN}"
load_api_credentials()

def uploadconfig():
    put_req = requests.request("PUT", UPLOAD_URL, data=UPLOAD_FILE_NAME)
    print(put_req.text)
uploadconfig()
```

I was trying to execute above script, it’s triggering terraform plan initially, but nit providing the planning details. It was continuously running.

Once I tried few hours later, then I am getting bad request error. So wanted to know whether upload_url is valid for certain time period or it’s static once generated

Comment: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/api-docs/configuration-versions#upload-configuration-files `The URL is provided in the upload-url attribute when creating a configuration-versions resource. After creation, the URL is hidden on the resource and no longer available.`

Comment: yeah, then I saw. That's a reason I appended upload_url variable in above script which is basically done from other script.